# how to save update full calender events in server in asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-update

using full calender.js for booking purpose. how can i save updated events and delete events in server side using asp.net.
for example:

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event, element) {

```
    event.title = "CLICKED!";

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Net's Session from javascript and server side code to hold or get values.